# Entity Framework Cannot insert duplicate key in object

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

Can not find solution to my problem. I'm sorry, if I duplicate the Question.

I have relation in Entity Framework code first one to many:

```
[DataContract(IsReference = true)]
public class PricingPlan
{

    public PricingPlan()
    {
        UserProfiles = new List<UserProfile>();
    }

    [Key]
    [DataMember]
    public Guid PricingPlanId { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Type { get; set; }

    public ICollection<UserProfile> UserProfiles { get; set; }
}

[DataContract(IsReference = true)]
public class UserProfile : IdentityUser
{
    public DateTime JoinedOn { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastVisited { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }

    public Guid PricingPlanId { get; set; }
    public PricingPlan PricingPlan { get; set; }
}
```

In PricingPlan Table I have 2 rows Free and Pro

Whe user register, I want to add him to Free plan:

```
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [Route("Register")]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Register(RegisterBindingModel model)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        PricingPlan pp = UnitOfwork.PricingPlanRepository.FirstOrDefault(v => v.Type == "Free");

        UserProfile user = new UserProfile
        {
            UserName = model.UserName,
            Email = model.Email,
            EmailConfirmed = false,
            Location = model.Location,
            JoinedOn = DateTime.Now,
            LastVisited = DateTime.Now,
            PricingPlanId = pp.PricingPlanId,
            PricingPlan = pp
        };

        IdentityResult identityResult = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
```

I'm taking existing plan from Db and adding it to userProfile property, but when UserManager trying creat user, I'm getting exception:

> Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_dbo.PricingPlans'. Cannot
>   insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.PricingPlans'. The duplicate key
>   value is (a5139db8-64c1-49a2-97ef-55009259dc23).\r\nThe statement has
>   been terminated."

OnModelCreating I have this code:

```
  modelBuilder.Entity<UserProfile>().HasRequired<PricingPlan>(r=>r.PricingPlan).WithMany(c => c.UserProfiles).HasForeignKey(a=>a.PricingPlanId);
```

What is the right way to add existing entity to new entity in one to many relation in entity framework code first?

Comment: You don't need the line: `PricingPlan = pp`, you're aleady creating the relationship by adding `PricingPlanId = pp.PricingPlanId`

Comment: That is totally not an EF problem. The problem is that on the database you insert duplicate keys. Reading the error message makes this clear.

Comment: A actualy added PricingPlan = pp, because when I want to get UserProfile with PricingPlan - it is null, but LazyLoading is false

Comment: I now, that it is not EF problem, the question is how to add?

Comment: I have existing objects in db, and I just want map it to new UserProfile. And when I want to get UserProfile, it must be PricingPlan(not null) in property

Comment: You're saying that you're using lazy loading but your navigation properties are not virtual. If they're not virtual EF won't perform lazy loading on them (will not be able to create dynamic proxies).

Comment: I'm not using LazyLoading, I set it to false.

Comment: The problem is while you are creating new `UserProfile`, entity framework insert `pp(PricingPlan)` again to database which you selected before. it's odd why `EF` does not track selected `pp`. Post the code inside `UnitOfwork.PricingPlanRepository`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, I solved the problem.

I removed `PricingPlan = pp`, like markpsmith said. Then, when I wan to get UserProfile with attached entity Pricingplan in it,
 I just make Include:

```
this.Context.Set<UserProfile>().Include("PricingPlan").
```

But can not understand, why it is not included by default,
when `LazyLoading is set to false.`

Comment: _By default, Entity Framework 4 uses Lazy Loading.  You can disable it with this code:
context.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
Once this is done, dependent collections like the Comments property of a Post in our example will be null if they are not specifically included._.  From [here](http://ardalis.com/working-with-lazy-loading-in-entity-framework-code-first)